# How to display all post in wordpress, i am using pagination, so its display the post that display as per page no other of navigation other page

Tags: php, wordpress

Any WordPress experts, Please Help me.

I am trying to display all posts in the drop-down menu, I get result 12 results of drop-down options, but another second page (I am using pagination) post is not shown in the drop down menu, when I go to the second page I show that page posts dropdown result. I want to show all posts in the dropdown menu on every page pages.

Code:-

```
<?php 

 wp_list_pages(array('post_type'=>'brands')); 

?> 
<select class="form-control pdt-category-select search-space" id="brands" name="brands"> 
   <option>All</option> 
   <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { 
     echo '<option value="', $post->post_name, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>'; 
   }?> 
</select>
```

Comment: <?php wp_list_pages(array('post_type'=>'brands')); ?>
               <select class="form-control pdt-category-select search-space" id="brands" name="brands">
                  <option>All</option>
                
                 <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { 
            echo '<option value="', $post->post_name, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>';
        }?>
                </select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you called function but you didn't assign return value to any variable:

```
wp_list_pages(array('post_type'=>'brands'));
```

Edit it to:

```
$dropdown_posts = wp_list_pages(array('post_type'=>'brands'));
```

Function wp_list_pages is returning string in HTML format https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/. You don't need to loop it, just echo it:

```
<?php echo $dropdown_posts ?>
```

If  you rather loop through posts use function get_posts() like this:

```
<?php 

 $dropdown_posts = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'brands')); 

?> 
<select class="form-control pdt-category-select search-space" id="brands" name="brands"> 
   <option>All</option> 
   <?php foreach ($dropdown_posts as $post) { 
     echo '<option value="', $post->post_name, '"', $selected == $post->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $post->post_title, '</option>'; 
   }?> 
</select>
```